# How can I get a wife or daughter in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to settle down, and my friend says i can get a daughter and stuff, how do I?

PS.Is there jobs? Like, not quests, but actual jobs?

PPS.I dont have acces to any of the DLCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short:

- Befriend an NPC of opposite gender (doing some quest for them or such)
- Wear an Amulet of Mara (go to the temple in Riften if you don't have one)
- Talk to the NPC
- Go to Riften Temple to set up wedding
- Attend wedding

Congratulations!

You need the Hearthfire DLC to adopt children.

There aren't any day jobs (unless you count the small misc. tasks like chopping wood). I guess you could do a radiant quest for the companions every day and call yourself a "hunter", but that's about it. I guess any faction that has repeatable quests could qualify as a "job".

More info on marriage: [Uesp:Marriage](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage)

More info on "jobs": [Uesp:Tasks](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Activities#Tasks)

Comment: I dont have hearthfire, but thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Get the adopt mod.

Comment: @Jim Jones why not just get hearthfire?

Comment: @Gamer3001 It's another idea, and also this has been a few months old.